# Share File data between components angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I am using a reactive form to capture some inputs and a file from a user using a component  The ts and html pages of  the component is like below

```
    import {  Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-import-file',
      templateUrl: './import-file.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./import-file.component.css']
    })
    export class ImportFileComponent implements OnInit {

      orderImportForm: FormGroup; 
      public importFile: File;

      constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute,private fb: FormBuilder) {
      }

      getfile(e: any) {
        const fileList: FileList = e.target.files;
        this.importFile = fileList[0]; 
      }

      ngOnInit(): void { 
        this.orderImportForm = this.fb.group({
          yourReferenceNumber: [''],
          orderType: ['']
        }); 
      }

      onSubmit() {
        console.log(this.importFile); // this will give you the file    
        console.log(this.orderImportForm.value);        
        if (this.importFile?.type=="pdf") {
          this.router.navigate(['../component1'], { relativeTo: this.route });
        }
        else {
          this.router.navigate(['../component2'], { relativeTo: this.route });      
        }
      }
    } 


    // HTML 


    <form [formGroup]="orderImportForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
          <h2>Import a Purchase Order</h2>
          <div class="bg-light card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend>Upload Reference No</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="yourReferenceNumber">
                </div>
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend>CSV Excel Or PDF File</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="file" (change)="getfile($event)" class="form-control-file" />
                </div>
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend>Upload Type?</legend>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="orderType" formControlName="orderType" value="1" />
                    Instant
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="orderType" formControlName="orderType" value="2" />
                    Later
                  </label>
                </div>
              </fieldset>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>   
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
          <p class="my-5">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </p>     
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
```

On form submission the values of file and form elements is getting captured correctly. As next step i have to load another component based on file type (if pdf file is uploaded showing component1 , otherwise showiing component2 )

Inside these components i have to read the file contents and process further. How can i read the content of importFile on another components ?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Can this be done in Angular?

Comment: This seems like an issue you would want to use a ``service`` for. You could also use ``@Output``, but I don't think that's possible if you're redirecting the user to a new route/component.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has probably more than one solution, but when reading your question I was thinking of creating a service. Unlike components, services are injectable which means multiple other components can use the contents of a service.

I would create an `Observable` inside this service to which you emit for example `importFile` or anything you want basically whenever you want.
From another component you import this service and subscribe to the observable. Then once a value is emitted on it you catch it and handle it in whatever way you want.

In case of the two possible components you might want to do something with `*ngIf` and `async pipe`.

Everything related to observables can be found here: https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable
The rest is just native Angular stuff.